# Sugar orm, how to delete duplicate records?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, sugarorm

I'm using sugar orm for a high scores database, and after a lot of searching(because the documentation is very pure and also some links are dead), I've managed to save and list the records from the database. Unfortunately I cannot find out how to delete the duplicated score records, or how to update a record instead of saving a new one in case the name and high score values are the same.
I found that this can be done with something like this:

```
getWritableDatabase().execSQL("delete from highscores where _id not in (SELECT MIN(_id ) FROM highscores GROUP BY highscores_id)");
}
```

but how can I do it with sugar orm in which I don't know if it even has a id field or its name ?

**UPDATE:**
Following @Juancortes' s advice I'm trying to check for the current player, if the current score exists in database, before add the record:

```
 private void saveScore(){
    int total;
    total=checkList();
    if(total>0) {
        HighScoresDB highScores = new HighScoresDB(tvPlName.getText().toString(), total);
        highScores.save();
    }
}
private int checkList(){
String tempName=tvPlName.getText().toString();
List<HighScoresDB> check = HighScoresDB.find(HighScoresDB.class, "person = ?",tempName);
ArrayList<Integer> templist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<check.size();i++){
        templist.add(check.get(i).score);
    }
int total = Integer.valueOf(totalPts.getText().toString());
if(templist.contains(total)) {
    total = 0;
}else{
    total=Integer.valueOf(totalPts.getText().toString());
}
    return total;
}
```

I get a list with the existing records for current player using sugar orm. After I'm checking if the list contain the current score value, and if is true I set it to "0". Then in "saveScore()" method I save a record only if the score value is greater that "0". But this doesn't work and I keep getting double, triple etc records. What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2:**
Seems that "contains" doesn't work for the list with the database objects directly. So I created an ArrayList with only the scores(code updated too), and I used that list to check if the total exists. Now seems that works fine and don't created double records.

Comment: so if it is such poorly documented stuff, why to use this at all, why not to use http://greendao-orm.com/ ?

Comment: You should probably override the `save` method of your highscore model , which should extend `SugarRecord`, to check for duplicates before saving. That's a lot better than deleting afterwards

Comment: I will concider greendao, but now is the only thing left, so I would like to find a way.

Comment: @JuanCortés I'm thinking about this too but again I don't know how to check for dublicates with sugar orm query.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but you can use the executeQuery() method for a raw custom query. Here is an example of a query that will remove duplicates:

```
DELETE tableName FROM tableName LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT MIN(table_primary_key) AS rowId, col1, col2, col3
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
) as KeepRows ON tableName.table_primary_key = KeepRows.rowId
WHERE KeepRows.rowId IS NULL
```

Compares all the rows, finds any duplicates, deletes them.

This will execute in SQL without having to pull back all the records, though you can modify it to a SELECT and then use the SugarORM delete functionality. That will increase memory usage though.